# What should be the status code for search results page

Tags: seo

Website I am working on has a Search Results Page. Depending upon the number of results returned from the database, it also displays page numbers. User can click on the page numbers to go to that page. What is better for SEO :

- Should each page be a separate url? If yes should page number be a query parameter or path parameter ?
- If the Search Result has 100 pages  today  but 70 pages after a month, should the URLs for the deleted pages  show  410 or 404 or should I redirect to page 1 ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the SEO tag states: GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Comment: Unable to delete. I get   error "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Answer (score 1):

For SEO, you should prevent your search results from getting crawled at all.  Google doesn't want to index search results.  It is bad user experience when clicking from the Google search results takes the user to other search results.

If you allow your search results to be crawled and indexed, Google could penalize your entire site from getting indexed at all.

Reference: [Matt Cutts -- Search results in search results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/)

Use `robots.txt` to disallow all search result pages on your site.  Then Googlebot will never see the status codes.

Comment: I agree with that in general but the search results such as   "boats for sale", "Boats for sale in Georgia",  "Boats for sale in Texas" etc  should be indexed because I see those searches in google.  If you search for "Boats for sale in Miami"  you can see many indexed pages

Comment: I would expect that almost all of the sites have full pages about boats for sale in Miami and not just a link to their site search results.

Comment: If your question is about pagination in general (not just for search results) see [this answer of mine on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/123637/14543).

Comment: You can google for 'boats for sale in miami' and click on any site. It will take you to the search results. It also makes sense because when as a user I search for 'boats for sale in Miami', I want to see those links in google search results

Comment: If I were looking for boats for sale in Miami, I would want to see listings of boats for sale, not search results.  I'd want features to be able to filter and sort those listings.  I'd want detailed information such as condition and age for each listing.  I'd want some sort of value indicator (good deal, bad deal) for each listing.  You can't get that with search.